# Translating with sed command

Tags: sed

With the following script I'm trying to read a text file (italian.txt), and translate from this file all words from Italian into English and save the output in another text file (english.txt). I have to use `sed` command with the global command `g` so that I translate every appearance of the word.

It's not working correctly but I don't know what goes wrong. Can somebody help me?

```
cat italian.txt | sed -i 's/sole/sun/g' | 's/penna/pen/g' > english.txt

exit 0
```

Comment: Maybe a typo, but you're missing `sed` after the second pipe: `cat italian.txt | sed -i 's/sole/sun/g' | sed -i 's/penna/pen/g' > english.txt`

Comment: You seem to be missing a `sed` after the second pipe?

Comment: When executing the script it says sed: no input files.

@JohnN

Comment: You're using the `-i` flag to indicate editing files "in place"; however, that requires a file, and you're instead using `stdin` (the `stdout` from `cat`). You can remove the `-i` (from both `sed`s), and it should work fine.

Comment: Yes, it worked! @JohnN Thank you very much!

Comment: I was going to say "No need, and I'll upvote yours!", but I see you've deleted your answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your script:

1. You need to add a second `sed` after the second pipe (`|`).
2. `sed -i` tells `sed` to edit files "in-place", but there is no file specified - `sed` is using `stdin`, coming from `cat`. You can safely remove the `-i` and your script should now work.

The fixed script should be:

```
cat italian.txt | sed 's/sole/sun/g' | sed 's/penna/pen/g' > english.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using it wrong.

First, you don't need cat. `sed` can take filename to read. Like this:

```
sed 's/sole/sun/g' italian.txt
```

Second, you don't need pipe-redirection for next `sed`-expression. If you need it, it should looks like this:

```
sed 's/sole/sun/g' italian.txt | sed 's/penna/pen/g' > english.txt
```

, but it is extra work. `sed` can process more than one expression. You can split them by «;» or give them to `sed` as command line arguments with `-e` before each one.

In sum, command looks so:

```
sed 's/sole/sun/g; s/penna/pen/g' italian.txt > english.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If you had a file with word pairs, for example

```
sole sun
penna pen
```

... and so on for many words in Italian and English (there's no practical limit other than memory), then you could create a `sed` script

```
s/\<sole\>/sun/g
s/\<penna\>/pen/g
```

... (where `\<word\>` will match only the word `word` and not e.g. `words` or `reword`) like this:

```
$ awk '{ printf("s/\\<%s\\>/%s/g\n", $1, $2) }' pairs.txt >translate.sed
```

Then you could apply that `sed` script to a text file:

```
$ sed -f translate.sed italian.txt >english.txt
```

Comment: @ Kusalananda, very cool! +1

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary and redundant to overwrite the contents of italian.txt since the output of `sed` is being redirected to another file called english.txt and saved anyway. It's also possible to eliminate the useless use of `cat`

```
sed -e 's/sole/sun/g' -e 's/penna/pen/g' italian.txt | tee english.txt
```

- `sed` allows multiple `-e` switches, which allows replacing more than one thing at a time.
- `tee` can be used for data redirection (e.g. to another file called english.txt).

Answer (score 0):

A variant of @Kusalanananda idea:

```
$ cat dict
sole:sun
penna:pen

$ sed -f <(sed -r 's!(.+):(.+)!s/\\<\1\\>/\2/g!' dict)   it.txt >en.txt
```